# Your program is still running..python....where is my mistake..?

Tags: python

```
x=int(input(1))
y=int(input(2))

if x==y:
    print('x and y are equal')
else:
    print('x and y are not equal')

print('thanks')
```

Comment: Looks like the error doesn't come from program itself, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: do you really want to use the numbers `1` and `2` as your input prompts? otherwise the program seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, you could have found this info in any tutorial, book, or question searched on here. Anyways....

Input takes the text which will be displayed to the user when prompted in the console.

```
>>> input("Enter a number: ")
Enter a number:
```

Then, I could type in the number I wanted and hit enter. (Reverting to previous line)

```
Enter a number: 4
```

Then, the value you assigned input to would have "4". Note that this is a string.

Hence, `int(input(1))` isn't doing what you think it is. Your program is still "running" because it's waiting for user input.

```
x=int(input("Enter first number: "))
y=int(input("Enter second number: "))

if x==y:
    print('x and y are equal')
else:
    print('x and y are not equal')
print('thanks')
```

Output:

```
Enter first number: 1
Enter second number: 1
x and y are equal
thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

It keeps running because x and y are inputs. Inputs ask you to type in something to give them a value. Remove the input(...). Also, int() is unnecessary because 1 and 2 are already integers.

```
x = 1
y = 2
if x == y:
    print("x and y are equal")
else:
    print("x and y are not equal")
print("thanks")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Mr. Nitesh,**

Your program is not wrong when you execute your program also get output but programming or standard way is not valid your program.

If you ar beginner in python first read the basic programming in deep and read programming standard. I give below website for python... 
1) http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/contributing/python.html (Python Programming Standard)
2) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/ (Python Learning)
3) https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ (Python Learning)

**I give your question of answer is below,**

```
x = int(input("Enter the value of x: "))
y = int(input("Enter the value of Y: "))

print "Now check both are equal or not..."

if x != y:
   print('x and y are not equal.')
elif x == y :`enter code here`
   print('x and y are equal')

print('Thank you.')
```

Comment: Nice. i am new in python i learn all website give by you.